# Centering images in menu?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a list of links such as:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="icon.png" /> Text</a></li>
```

The point is icons just like the text next to them are at the same level and I want them to be a little below, so it will look like they're centered.

I know it's hard to get, so check the link below.

There's a live demo (two images below, the first one shows how it looks now and the second one how I want it to look):

http://jsfiddle.net/3yZTg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vertical-align: middle on the images.

```
li a img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, and this behaves more uniformly across browsers, you can make it a bg:

```
<li><a href="#"><span style="padding-left: 12px; display: block; background: transparent url(icon.png) left center no-repeat; float: left;">Text</span></a></li>
```

Comment: So you would either need a class for each icon, or inline styles. Plus, you couldn't have icons of varying sizes. Not cool.

Comment: @Karpie Nonsense. You can put most of the stuff in the styles. All you really need to do inline is `background-image` and `padding-left`. That allows you for variable icon width. You can tweak the height and padding for all `li span` elements globally.

Comment: If you're a purist with an agenda, I guess you can use a class for each link and move the stylings into the linked css files! WOOO! EVERYTHING IS COOL NOW! ¬_¬